# ScoreDirector problem change entity lookup

Tags: java, timefold

I can investigate this myself, but figured i'd put the question out there in case anyone else stumbles across this.

I would like to be able to "remove" a planning entity via a `ProblemChange`. I was hoping to be able to do this by planning ID. Does `ProblemChangeDirector.lookUpWorkingObjec`t support lookup by ID, or must the entire entity be passed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, `ProblemChangeDirector` does not support lookup by id. What you can do is create an "empty" entity that only has its planning id set and use that to lookup the entity:

```java
MyEntity lookupEntity = new MyEntity(id);
problemChangeDirector.removeEntity(lookupEntity, workingSolution.getMyEntityList()::remove);
```